# Function in AngularJS doesn't return value back to caller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, debugging

I am learning AngularJS and creating a small playground for fun. Following code is what I have but I have no idea why the return value from getMessage() doesn't go back to caller. Following is the code

**msg.html**

```
<html ng-app="CodeApp">
<head>
<!-- Libs JS -->
<script src="asset/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/lib/ui-route/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/lib/angular-base64/angular-base64.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/msg-mol.js"></script>
<script src="js/msg-service.js"></script>
<script src="js/msg-controller.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="MsgController">
  Msg: {{message}}
</body>

</html>
```

**msg-mol.js**

```
var app = angular.module('CodeApp', []);
```

**msg-controller.js**

```
app.controller('MsgController', ['$scope', 'MsgService',  function($scope, MsgService) {
     var msg = MsgService.getMessage();
     //debugger; (2)
     $scope.message = msg;
}]);
```

**msg-service.js**

```
 app.factory('MsgService', [ '$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getMessage : function(){
            $http.get('/api/codes').success(function(data) {
                var str = "total is " + data.total;
                //debugger;  (1)
                return str;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

1) The output on browser is just "msg:" and {{message}} is empty. I am monitoring the backend and it is pretty sure /api/codes/ have been called to backend and str will be "Total is 35" in debugger mode.

2) when I run the debug mode in chrome, I realized debugger (2) statement has been called before debugger (1). I have no clue about this as getMessage() should be called before debugger(1) stmt.

Comment: You can also do this using `callbacks`. Refer this => http://plnkr.co/edit/25fUq97MSDkeshNkBTjY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return promise.

Like this

```
getMessage: function() {
    return $http.get('/api/codes').success(function(data) {
        var str = "total is " + data.total;
        //debugger;  (1)
        return str;
    });
}
```

And also have to handle callback using then

```
MsgService.getMessage().then(function(msg){
  $scope.message = msg;
});
```

Comment: then Anik and Rayon, it works! Where can I find the list of async function (i.e. .success(), .then())? I am new to AJAX programming

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `return` from the `getMessage` function. Change it to i.e.:

```
app.factory('MsgService', [ '$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getMessage : function(){
            return $http.get('/api/codes').success(function(data) {
                var str = "total is " + data.total;
                return str;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then inside your controller you need to observe the result:

```
app.controller('MsgController', ['$scope', 'MsgService',  function($scope, MsgService) {
     MsgService.getMessage().then(function($scope){
         $scope.message = msg;
     });
}]);
```

The [`$http.get`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) returns a [`Promise`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) that will be resolved when the request to server ends. Since it's [asynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)) you need to attach a callback to it in order to process the results.

Answer (score 0):

Better to return a promise and resolve the promise on your controller.

In your service,

```
getMessage: function () {
  return $http.get('/api/codes');
}
```

In your controller:

```
getMessage.success(function (data) {
  $scope.message = data.total;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Look at this example with code..
>   check it Example you can show firstly first debugger call and after another .. I know i do not give example with service you can understand.

```js
var app = angular.module('CodeApp', []);

app.controller('MsgController', ['$scope','MsgService',  function($scope, MsgService) {
     var msg = MsgService.getMessage();
     alert(2);
     debugger;// (2)
     $scope.message = msg;
}]);

app.factory('MsgService', [ '$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getMessage : function(){


                var str = "total is";
                alert(1);
                debugger;  //(1)
                return str;

        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="CodeApp">
<head>
<!-- Libs JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>  
<script src="asset/lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/lib/ui-route/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/lib/angular-base64/angular-base64.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="MsgController">
  Msg: {{message}}
</body>

</html>
```